# Does a model.save() expect to have the full updated JSON returned from the server?

Tags: json, backbone.js, marionette

My model has maybe 20 attributes available for updating in an HTML form. When the user hits "Submit" I check to see which fields have changed, serialize only those into a `data` variable and do a `model.save(data)`. If it's successful the API we've build simply sends back `{"status":"success"}`. So far this is working, but I'm wondering:

Does Backbone expect to get the full JSON back from the API for that particular model, or is a simple status fine? If it's the latter, how do I best ensure that the view is in sync with the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO, Backbone doesn't expect any response back from the API. The model which you save for the first time doesn't have an `id`, so mostly the API should return the new generated `id` which is then set in to the `model`.

To ensure the `model` is in sync with the database have a look at `model.fetch()` [here](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch).